# Using cast "decimal:2" on model returns string. Only "float" cast returns actual number

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 with MySQL 8.

This works:

```
protected $casts = [
    'amount' => 'float'
];
```

This doesn't work (returns string):

```
protected $casts = [
    'amount' => 'decimal:2'
];
```

I'm trying to avoid float for money values.

Comment: The decimal cast is a string cast (honestly I found it hard to figure this out without [looking through the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ea6237a415fa61a9d479e699f6e9f7a98f41fcd7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L1255))

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to avoid float for money values.

Then why are you expecting a float?

If you want to handle monetary values correctly the you should either use numeric-string (a string that passes is_numeric()) and use bcmath (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) for all calculations.

Or use the ext-decimal extension http://php-decimal.io/#introduction

Answer (score 0):

add this in your model

```
public function getAmountAttribute($value) {
    return round($value, 1);
}
```